# Containerd-shim hangs when running docker run

Tags: docker, containerd

My problem is that from time to time, when I try to start a new container with `docker run`, it just hangs forever. All the running containers keep working fine, but I'm unable to start any container.

The only way of getting out of there is with Ctrl+C, but then I can't remove the failed container (nor the associated image, of course). What I've found so far is that the associated `containerd-shim` process keeps running, and when I term it (it responds to TERM, no need to KILL), then everything unstucks and if I tried and failed to remove the container, it's removed in that moment. I still can't create any new container with `docker run` though.

If I restart the docker service it stops happening... for a while. Of course this is less than ideal so I would like to find the root cause. I've been unable to find any containerd logs that can give me a clue of what's happening, so I'm here to see if someone had a similar problem and how he/she solved  it or if someone with a deep knowledge of docker can give me a thread to pull.

I'm using docker engine v19.03.6 with containerd v1.4.4.

I'm not running out of memory. I've checked that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with an upgrade. There have been quite a few releases since 19.03.6 and containerd 1.4.4 that may have fixed this issue:

- https://github.com/containerd/containerd/tags
- https://github.com/moby/moby/tags